# Why do MSVC and Clang produce different outputs for the same function template call?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

After messing around with concepts I came across something in visual studio that I didn't understand, although I don't know if the issue here is anything to do with concepts specifically. I'm sure there's a reason for this behaviour, but it would be great if someone could explain. There are two parts to this question. For the following snippet:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template <typename PolicyType, typename T, typename... Ts>
concept concept_policy = requires(Ts&&... args) 
{
    { PolicyType::template Create<T>(args...) } -> std::same_as<T*>;
};

struct basic_policy
{
    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    static T* Create(Ts&&... args)
    {
        return new T { std::forward<Ts>(args)... };
    }
};

struct type_a
{
    int m_val;
};

template <concept_policy<int> TPolicy = basic_policy>
static void DoSomething()
{
    //works on msvc, msvc needs the "template" for no args, but not with?
    {
        type_a* type1 = TPolicy::Create<type_a>(5); //why is this fine without template?
        type_a* type2 = TPolicy::template Create<type_a>(); //why does this require template if the above doesn't?
    }

    // //clang requires both to have "template"
    // {
    //     type_a* type1 = TPolicy::template Create<type_a>(5);
    //     type_a* type2 = TPolicy::template Create<type_a>();
    // }
}

int main()
{

    DoSomething();

    {
        //both versions compile fine without "template"
        basic_policy policy;
        type_a* type1 = basic_policy::Create<type_a>(5);
        type_a* type2 = basic_policy::Create<type_a>(); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why do msvc and clang produce different outputs here? Msvc is fine having the "template" omitted for the call with arguments, but not without
2. Using a similar policy design, is there any way around prefixing the Create with "template"? Ideally I'd like to be able to call `TPolicy::Create<type>(...);`

Comment: `template` is needed within `DoSomething` but not within `main` because `TPolicy` is a dependent name. msvc has a long history of implementing templates not in accordance to the standard. it has improved recently, but the old non-compliant behaviour is not completely gone yet.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks, I knew about that briefly but wasn't sure why one call was ok and not the other. Also noticed that if TPolicy is a variable, the "template" can be omitted entirely on msvc but I would guess this is wrong. Should I be following what clang is telling me then?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I don't think it is the related to history here. It seems more related to concept/constraint. From `concept_policy<int>`, `TPolicy::Create<type_a>(5);` should exist. (msvc is not coherent, as then `TPolicy::Create` is template and it would not be required for `TPolicy::Create<type_a>();`).

Comment: @Jarod42 A compiler is not required to "work backwards" through a concept to determine that if `TPolicy` satisfies `concept_policy<int>` then `TPolicy::create` must name a template. That would probably be impossible to implement with any sort of consistency. The `template` is required because `TPolicy::create` is a dependent name, in a context allowing expressions, and not "a member of the current instantiation".

Comment: Or actually I think this is "ill-formed no diagnostic required" if the template is never instantiated.

Comment: Nearly as minimal as I could get it: https://godbolt.org/z/hqG5Pn7dP - The concept doesn't make any difference. MSVC's helpful error message for `TPolicy::Create<type_a>(5)` disappears if any template declared in any scope is named `Create`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang is correct: the call to `TPolicy::Create<type_a>` requires the word `template` because `TPolicy` is a dependent type.

Specifically, according to the standard, when we have a fragment of the form `T::m<` where `T` is a dependent type other the current instantiation, the compiler must assume that `<` is the less-than operator, not the beginning of a template argument list. If you mean `<` as a template argument list, then you must prefix `m` with the keyword `template`.

This behaviour is specified in [[temp.names]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3). A `<` that doesn't satisfy any of the conditions listed must be interpreted to mean the less-than operator; the compiler cannot use contextual information to determine that it means the beginning of a template argument list.

As for why MSVC sometimes fails to diagnose the violation, I am not sure.

There is no way to make `TPolicy::Create<type>(...);` just work without the `template` keyword. If you really hate writing `template`, you have to restructure your code so that `Create` is a non-member, sort of like `std::get` in the standard library (which would have to be invoked in the form `.template get<i>()` if it were a class member and the object expression were of dependent type). I guess in this case, `Create` could be a class template that takes the policy class as one of its template arguments, and the type you want to create as another. I have been told that people often do make their templates into non-members for this exact reason (to avoid having to write `template`). I think that's a big mistake. It's better to write `template` than to choose a less natural design.

Comment: The reason standart requires the `template` is so that static analysis would be easier to perform and have no ambiguities. MSVC does not perform static analysis - instead it just compiles the templates on instantiation.